# Cmake build tests files

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm working on a project composed of some components, each of them have to communicate with a sensor like GPS or IMU.
The structure of the folder is the following:

```
/
  build
  src
    errorCodes.h
    Component.h
    Component.cpp
    IMU.h
    IMU.cpp
  tests
    imu
      main.cpp
      CMakeLists.txt
```

What I would like to do is to compile the `main.cpp` file in the test directory linking the implementation in the src file.

The `CMakeLists.txt` file is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

set (PROJECT_NAME imu)
set (DUT_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../src)

project (${PROJECT_NAME})

find_package (Qt5Core REQUIRED)

set  (project_SOURCES main.cpp ${DUT_DIR}/IMU.h ${DUT_DIR}/IMU.cpp ${DUT_DIR}/Component.h ${DUT_DIR}/Component.cpp ${DUT_DIR}/errorCodes.h)

include_directories (${DUT_DIR})

ADD_EXECUTABLE  (${PROJECT_NAME} ${project_SOURCES}
                           ${project_FORMS_HEADERS}
                           ${project_HEADERS_MOC})

qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Core SerialPort)
```

But when I run the `make` command I receive the following errors:

```
CMakeFiles/imu.dir/home/thegr8/Desktop/3d-6dof-scanner/src/IMU.cpp.o: In function `IMU::IMU()':
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `vtable for IMU'
CMakeFiles/imu.dir/home/thegr8/Desktop/3d-6dof-scanner/src/IMU.cpp.o: In function `IMU::~IMU()':
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `vtable for IMU'
CMakeFiles/imu.dir/home/thegr8/Desktop/3d-6dof-scanner/src/Component.cpp.o: In function `Component::Component(QObject*)':
Component.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `vtable for Component'
CMakeFiles/imu.dir/home/thegr8/Desktop/3d-6dof-scanner/src/Component.cpp.o: In function `Component::~Component()':
Component.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `vtable for Component'
```

What I do wrong?

---

## Update

Now I create a library in the build directory and I link them from the test file as suggested in the comments.

When I compile the test project I receive the following errors:

```
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::QSerialPortInfo(QSerialPortInfo const&)'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x28b): undefined reference to `QSerialPort::QSerialPort(QObject*)'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x2af): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::portName() const'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::description() const'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x3d7): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::manufacturer() const'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x46b): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::portName() const'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x488): undefined reference to `QSerialPort::setPortName(QString const&)'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0x560): undefined reference to `QSerialPort::setBaudRate(int, QFlags<QSerialPort::Direction>)'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0xada): undefined reference to `QSerialPort::error() const'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0xb46): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::~QSerialPortInfo()'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0xb91): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::~QSerialPortInfo()'
IMU.cpp:(.text+0xd37): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::~QSerialPortInfo()'
```

both projects are compiled with `set(AUTOMOC ON)`

Comment: Do IMU and Component inherit from QObject and define Q_OBJECT? In that case try to add `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` to your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: By the way...consider building your src/ stuff as a library and then just make your tests link to it. You could also use CMake's `ctest` runner (and possibly QtTest) to run the tests.

Comment: @juzzlin - I have updated my question, now I receive `undefined reference` relative to the `QSerialPortInfo` library

Comment: Are you linking to the Qt serial port library in the test?

Comment: @juzzlin - Yes with the command `qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Core SerialPort)`

Comment: And what about the library target? Do you have something like `add_library(imuLib your_lib_sources)` and `qt5_use_modules(imuLib Core SerialPort)` ?

Comment: @juzzlin - Yes, exactly so

Comment: And your main test binary should have `target_link_libraries(imu imuLib)`.

Comment: In any case there's now something missing, because the Qt lib is not linked in. You can use `make VERBOSE=1` to see the actual commands CMake is using.

Comment: @juzzlin - Yes, I use `find_library (IMU_LIB IMU ${TOP_DIR}/build)` to find it and then `target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${IMU_LIB})` to link them

Comment: Ok, that might be the problem because I guess it doesn't find any IMU_LIB and the variable is empty. You don't have to use `find_library()` if the library is built in the same project tree. Just link to the library name.

Comment: In my projects I use `add_subdirectory()` so that CMake builds the library as a sub-project and there's another CMakeLists.txt for the library. It can be used without `find_library()`in the main CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Ok, so I should create a general `CMakeLists.txt` that add the `src` directory for build the components and the `tests` directory to generate the tests, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work. CMake's subdirectory feature is pretty nice.

Comment: If you want, you can take a look how it's done in https://github.com/juzzlin/DustRacing2D, for example.

Comment: @juzzlin - Thank you very much, it works!